# Retrieve lost account password?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm a bit upset about my whole situation,

I used my LastPass password manager in Chrome to generate a 16 character special password. I put that password in my LastPass secure notes, go back to it later and its my last version (outdated without ethereum password). I still had Ethereum Wallet open at the time, so I went to Accounts backup -> Accounts and Application Data. Would I be able to retreive my password after I backed up the folders it wanted me to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backing up accounts will only back up your accounts. The accounts are encrypted with the password you created. Without the password, you cannot do anything with the accounts.

This is why you make a password, make sure you have access to the password, check that the password does indeed unlock the wallet, put the password and private key on a USB drive, and then and only then transfer any funds to that account.

Comment: Damn, well I just lost 12 eth. Thanks for explaining though.